# cannot passing value from hidden input form with php

Tags: php, forms

i hava a form , and value of input coming from mysql query , the radio value passing without problem , but hidden input passing only first hidden input on page .

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="<? echo $awardid ; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="point" value="<? echo $point ; ?>" />
```

Note : the Variables in while loop

on html code of form like that , i think the problem is (name of hidden input is a same)

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="point" value="3">

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="point" value="5">

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="point" value="8">

elc ...
```

Comment: echo your values, even though they are hidden.

Comment: okay i edit my code , but this not my problem , thnx

Comment: Are short open tags "on"? If not, do `value="<?php echo $point; ?>"`

Comment: where are you passing it from and to where?

Comment: the code is passing first value hidden input found it on page , i passing from an to same page .

Comment: Plus, it's normal that only one value will be passed, since they're all named the same. You may want to use checkboxes instead and use an array such as `name="checkbox[]"` then use a `foreach` loop to retrieve the chosen values.

Comment: @ Fred -ii , the problem not on print a var , problem on the html code becouse when i Change `hidden` input to `radio` it passing whithout problem

Comment: @ Fred -ii , okay now you are understand me ... but i cannot Change it to checkbox , i want it on hidden becouse i want passing this value with value of radio by auto . `when i Choose radio 1 passing with it 5 point .. elc

Comment: I need to know how you're defining `$point` in your code; which isn't shown. You'll need to use an `isset()` and define that variable. Show your full code.

Comment: sorry how i use  `isset()` ? you mean like that `if ( isset($_POST['point']))`

Comment: my code is a plugin of `vBulletin` forum

Comment: That would work, just as long as you're using `$point=$_POST['point'];` somewhere in your code.

Comment: sure i get value by `$_POST['point']` , can you answer me about one Question , why if input is radio it passing correct value , but if input is hidden  it passing only first value found it on page

Comment: Probably because they're being treated as "selected" in a hidden manner. For example: You have 3 radio buttons, each of the same name. You select "one", because radio buttons only let you select one, right? Well, it's the same logic for hidden elements of the same name.

Comment: okay i think that too , but i don't know until now what's the Solution

Answer (score 0):

you can change the name of the hidden field with `point[]`. while you request the result you will get all the values of hidden fields in array.

Comment: i don't want passing all values of hidden , i want passing one value with a value of radio

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to simply see the values of your hidden input fields?  To do so, do something similar to this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="point[]" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="point[]" value="5">
<input type="hidden" name="point[]" value="8">

$post = $_POST['point'];
echo $post[0] ."<br>";
echo $post[1] ."<br>";
echo $post[2];
```

You'll get the output of

```
3
5
8
```

Comment: i want passing value of hidden input with value of radio input,when i Choose a one of radio .. like : if i Choose radio 1 passing with it the value of hidden 3 .. elc .. note : value of hidden is a var on loop .

Comment: So you want to get the value of the currently selected radio button?

Comment: yes , i want pass hidden value with currently selected radio button -  value of radio passing already .. the problem in hidden value it get only first value on page all time